# replace values in two columns using awk

Tags: awk

Hi I have a text file that look like this

```
P383      0         II-5    2     0     1/2   0       0       42.7    0       54.67   0      
T528      0         P383    2     0     1/2   0       0       0       0       34.06   0      
T529      III-8     0       2     0     0     0       0       0       0       37.74   0      
T530      III-8     0       2     0     0     0       0       0       0       36.73   0      
3B888     III-4     III-5   2     0     1/2   38.4    0       0       0       44.38   0
```

I want to replace the 0 in columns 2, 3 and 5 with " " (a blank), I know how to do it for one column

The desired output would be

```
P383                II-5    2           1/2   0       0       42.7    0       54.67   0      
T528                P383    2           1/2   0       0       0       0       34.06   0      
T529      III-8             2           0     0       0       0       0       37.74   0      
T530      III-8             2           0     0       0       0       0       36.73   0      
3B888     III-4     III-5   2           1/2   38.4    0       0       0       44.38   0
```

I know how to do it for a single column

```
 awk '$3=="0"{$3=" "}; {print}' file
```

But how I do it for the three columns at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: thanks @JNevill, but this command `awk '$2=="0" ; $3=="0" ; $5=="0" {$2=" ";$3=" ";$5=" "; print}' file` does not produce the desired output, could you elaborate the answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{$2=$2==0?"":$2;$3=$3==0?"":$3;$5=$5==0?"":$5;} 1' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Adding a more generic solution by which you could pass number of fields in function as follows.

```
awk '
function check_fields(a){
  num=split(a,array,",");
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    $array[i]=$array[i]==0?"":$array[i]}
}
check_fields("2,3,5")
1
' OFS="\t"   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { split("2 3 5", tmp); for (i in tmp) flds[tmp[i]] }
    { for (i in flds) if ($i == 0) $i = ""; print }
' file
```